# Different Images for Button Onclick on iOS?

Tags: ios

I have a lot of buttons in my ViewController. I would like to have a new image show when the user has his finger on the button and the default image show once he takes his finger off the button.

Is this possible ?

Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit the nib, select the button, and in the right-hand utility pane, there should be a *State Config* drop down menu.  Select *Highlighted* and then set the image for that state.

Comment: ohhh, That was way too easy, Thanks a lot ! :)